# Import functions implicitly in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have 2 files.

```
//callee.js
const first = (name) => {
    return name;
}

const second = (name) => {
    return name + " is this";
}

module.exports = [
    first,
    second
]
//caller.js
const nav = require("./callee.js");

console.log(nav.first("bob")); //returns bob 
...(Object.values(nav)); //want something like this

first("bob"); // this should return bob
```

How do I call or destructure the import the variable **"nav"** in caller.js to get the above result?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
const [first, second] = require("./callee.js");

first("bob");
```

Comment: No, I dont want destructuring assignment like you've mentioned above.

What i want is the exported functions of the callee.js file to the implicitly present in the caller.js file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to type the variable names explicitly as in the excellent answer by Hao Wu, you can do this:

```
Object.assign(window, require('./callee.js'));
first('bob');
```

(Replace `window` with `global` in Node.js.)

**Important note:** This is horrible. I wrote it as a literal answer to the question, just to show it is possible. Please don't actually do this. Either keep the namespace (`nav.first`) or extract specific functions (as Hao Wu showed).

Comment: No, I dont want destructuring assignment like Hao Wu mentioned. What I want is the exported functions of the callee.js file to the implicitly present in the caller.js file.

Imagine initially having the first and second functions present initially in the caller.js file.
So to invoke the function. I write first("name") .

Now if I move the function out of the caller.js file , but still want to invoke it as earlier.